# Http Live Stream video Content

Tags: iphone, app-store, video-streaming, live-streaming

I am tryng to publish an application for Iphone on App store. But apple rejected my application . The reason was 9.4 Application using media content that more than 10 minutes must use HTTP live stream.

In my application it uses videos from many servers. like "http://video.teknomart.com.tr/3-13-2.mp4"

With media player controller I play the video. with initwithFileURL method. but I dont know How to use it with http live stream .I have looked up 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.
that apple referenced me. but I did not understand exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The request made by Apple is on the server side, not the iPhone one. You will need to segment each video file and create a playlist for them.

On Mac you can use mediafilesegmenter to segment and create the videofiles. OpenSource alternatives are also available.

This is done for controlling bandwidth over mobile networks. On wifi there is no restriction, so consider allowing the users to be able to play the video files on wifi only.

Answer (score 1):

> Application using media content that more than 10 minutes must use
>   HTTP live stream

You should have a apple recommended .m3u8 format playlist file in your server which can be distributed through HTTP Server if media you are streaming on your mobile phone is more than 10 minutes.

> In my application it uses videos from many servers. like "http://video.teknomart.com.tr/3-13-2.mp4"

This very thing that will breach their standards. Their are many solutions to this particular problem and depends on the scale of the project, service you are providing and server you wish to run.

If you are using video on demand, than you will need to segment all your contents to apple recommended format and store it in a ordinary server. In mac you can use [mediafilesegmenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW1), and for linux their are many opensource solutions such as [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

If you are providing live streaming than you would have a media server that will receive the media streams and than convert it into the apple recommended format and store into your server. While the distribution would be done by a HTTP Server.

[This post will provide you more information on Media Servers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312491/what-kind-of-server-is-required-for-live-streaming-of-video/40605788#40605788)