# What kind of server is required for live streaming of video?

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, avfoundation

I am making an iPhone application which will send video to a server for live streaming and I wanted to know that do we require a media server for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, You need to create a media server. You can send your streams to server from mobile using one of the many SDKs available.

For media server:
There are many ways that you can setup a server. For now lets see RTMP server which could be used with nginx. You can use hls(HTTP Live Streaming) as stated in above with this package. Here, the [RTMP Server](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) will receive the stream and converts it into the hls recommended format and HTTP server will distribute the streaming.

[This link will provide you more information](https://github.com/ltebean/Live).

Answer (score 0):

To distribute your media content you can use an ordinary HTTP server. If you want to provide live content, you need a server component that encapsulates your content into a format that can be distributed over HTTP.
Apple provides a suite of command line utilities that allow you to prepare your content. Just search for "HTTP Live Streaming Tools" at https://developer.apple.com/downloads

The [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH101-SW2) also is a good starting point.

Comment: I have seen several question on Stackoverflow related to live video streaming from iphone and most answers point to Apple's HLS but ever after going through the tutorial provided on apple developers website I didn't get any answer as to how can one send video to a server. The tutorials just speak about how to get a video on iPhone and not about the opposite direction.

Comment: Finally I have reached to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474871/whats-the-best-way-of-live-streaming-iphone-camera-to-a-media-server). where the person who asked this question gave a way to achieve this. Do you think this will work?